# How to properly access the app variable set by express in a node.js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm building a node.js server and my folder structure looks like this:

- server.js
- app/routes.js
- app/routes/users.js

My problem is that i'm not sure how can i use the `app` variable inside the users.js file. Do i have to require and setup express again in this file or is there a better/easier way to do it? Here is my sample code(just the bare minimum to understand my problem):

**server.js**

```
// Include our packages in our main server file
var express     = require('express');
var stormpath   = require('express-stormpath');
var app         = express();

// Init Stormpath for user management and authentication
app.use(stormpath.init(app));

// Load routes
require('./app/routes')(app);

// Start the server
app.listen(process.env.PORT);

// Stormpath will let you know when it's ready to start authenticating users.
app.on('stormpath.ready', function () {
  console.log('Your server is running on port ' + port + '.');
});
```

**app/routes.js**

```
// Import dependencies
const express   = require('express');
const stormpath = require('express-stormpath');

// Export the routes for our app to use
module.exports = function(app) {
  // Create API group routes
  const apiRoutes = express.Router();

  // User management: get users, invite users, view user profile
  var UsersRoute = require('./routes/users');
  apiRoutes.get('/memberinfo', stormpath.loginRequired, UsersRoute.memberInfo);

  // Set url for API group routes
  app.use('/', apiRoutes);
};
```

**app/routes/users.js**

```
// Protected route test
module.exports.memberInfo = function(req, res){
  //how do i access the "app" here?
    res.status(200).send({ user: req.user });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.memberInfo` method, you can use [`req.app`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.app) to access the `app` object that is associated with that request.

In cases where you aren't passed a `req` object that you can use in this way, then you need to initialize the module by calling a method on it and passing it the `app` object and the module can then store the `app` object locally so it can use it when desired.